# Can't install ingress-nginx with helm_release in Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, ingress-nginx

I am new In terraform and I create a Kubernetes Cluster in GKE and I want to install `ingress-nginx` with `helm`.

So, I wrote the following:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint
    token                  = data.google_client_config.main.access_token
    client_certificate     = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_controller" {
  name  = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "ingress-nginx"
  create_namespace = true

  wait = true
  timeout = 300
}
```

I get the following Error and I don't know how to solve it.
When I use helm to install ingress it works well but with Terraform I can't install it.

```
{"@level":"warn","@message":"Warning: Helm release \"ingress-nginx\" was created but has a failed status. Use the `helm` command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again.","@module":"terraform.ui","@timestamp":"2023-05-22T17:27:17.047328+03:00","diagnostic":{"severity":"warning","summary":"Helm release \"ingress-nginx\" was created but has a failed status. Use the `helm` command to investigate the error, correct it, then run Terraform again.","detail":"","address":"helm_release.nginx_ingress_controller","range":{"filename":"10-release.tf","start":{"line":13,"column":52,"byte":261},"end":{"line":13,"column":53,"byte":262}},"snippet":{"context":"resource \"helm_release\" \"nginx_ingress_controller\"","code":"resource \"helm_release\" \"nginx_ingress_controller\" {","start_line":13,"highlight_start_offset":51,"highlight_end_offset":52,"values":[]}},"type":"diagnostic"}
{"@level":"error","@message":"Error: failed pre-install: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"ingress-nginx-admission\" is forbidden: User \"lively-shelter-294615@appspot.gserviceaccount.com\" cannot delete resource \"clusterroles\" in API group \"rbac.authorization.k8s.io\" at the cluster scope: requires one of [\"container.clusterRoles.delete\"] permission(s).","@module":"terraform.ui","@timestamp":"2023-05-22T17:27:17.048209+03:00","diagnostic":{"severity":"error","summary":"failed pre-install: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"ingress-nginx-admission\" is forbidden: User \"lively-shelter-294615@appspot.gserviceaccount.com\" cannot delete resource \"clusterroles\" in API group \"rbac.authorization.k8s.io\" at the cluster scope: requires one of [\"container.clusterRoles.delete\"] permission(s).","detail":"","address":"helm_release.nginx_ingress_controller","range":{"filename":"10-release.tf","start":{"line":13,"column":52,"byte":261},"end":{"line":13,"column":53,"byte":262}},"snippet":{"context":"resource \"helm_release\" \"nginx_ingress_controller\"","code":"resource \"helm_release\" \"nginx_ingress_controller\" {","start_line":13,"highlight_start_offset":51,"highlight_end_offset":52,"values":[]}},"type":"diagnostic"}
```

I read a lot of similar questions but I can't solve the issue.

Comment: The error message claims a cluster RBAC permissions issue with your service account. Is that that not the root cause here?